# Codeigniter upload file and resize

Tags: codeigniter, upload, resize

I'm trying to resize pre-uploaded images and then send them to another server with FTP, but it doesnt seems to be working. The uploading is working fine, the ftp is working fine too but whenever I download the image and check the size it's just the same as the uploaded file.

This is my controller:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $image = $data['file_name'];

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './uploads/devices/'.$image;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width']    = 400;
            $config['height']   = 300;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $localPath = './uploads/devices/'.$image;
            $remotePath = 'webspace/httpdocs/uploads/devices/'.$image;

            $this->load->library('ftp');
            $config['hostname'] = '';
            $config['username'] = '';
            $config['password'] = '';
            $config['port']     = 21;
            $config['passive']  = TRUE;
            $this->ftp->connect($config);
            $this->ftp->upload($localPath, $remotePath);
            $this->ftp->close();
        }
```

What I want to achieve is upload the image, resize and replace it and upload the resized image after that.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: set log_threshold to 4 in config, check the logs to see what happens

Comment: @Ara I have done so but my logs folder is empty. I removed the images and the product and tried re-adding them but the log remains empty.

Comment: have you set the logs folder permissions to 777 (read&write for all)?

Comment: @Ara Yes I do, but won't permissions 644 be enough already? I had 644 before but changed it to 777 now, still nothing.

Comment: 666 is for writable files, 777 for writable folders and i mean the `logs folder` which is inside `application` folder (not talking about file), if you are sure it is 777 , check your config and make sure about $config['log_path'] = ''; ('' = default) and log_threshold = 4

Comment: I just checked and it actually never seems to load the img_lib, is there a logical explanation for this?

Comment: Here is a copy of the log: http://pastebin.com/fvSSBtsR

Comment: I don't see `Upload Class Initialized` line , are you sure you have loaded upload library and `$this->upload->do_upload()` returns TRUE? so whats inside it is executed?

Comment: In the code above I am clearly trying to load the image_lib as you can see after the upload im executing $this->load->library('image_lib');
Im also positive it returns true as the FTP class is being loaded and executed because the image can be found on my other server too.

Comment: Not talking about Image Library, i'm talking about Upload Class

Comment: Oh wait, yes the upload class is initialized. I only copied a small portion of the log but looks like I've missed just that one line.

Comment: instead of the code you have posted in your question above, just put `if ($this->upload->do_upload()){ echo 'YES'; }` do you see the YES when you open this page? if you are not, your if statement is not returning TRUE

Comment: It is returning "yes" when I put the echo there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Edit:

Used initialize to pass the configs instead of passing them directly to load->library:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $image = $data['file_name'];

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/devices/'.$image;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']    = 400;
        $config['height']   = 300;

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $localPath = './uploads/devices/'.$image;
        $remotePath = 'webspace/httpdocs/uploads/devices/'.$image;

        $this->load->library('ftp');
        $config['hostname'] = '';
        $config['username'] = '';
        $config['password'] = '';
        $config['port']     = 21;
        $config['passive']  = TRUE;
        $this->ftp->connect($config);
        $this->ftp->upload($localPath, $remotePath);
        $this->ftp->close();
    }
```

Comment: My ftp is being executed just fine so that cannot be the case. Same for my upload, the image IS being uploaded.

Comment: This seemed to have fixed my problem, I suppose the problem being I had to add the : $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

I'm not going to load the library inside my construct as there are only 2 functions inside there which require it.

Comment: Im still wondering how it got fixed because as far as I know the $this->image_lib->clear(); is only used when inside a loop that can have different values, and the $this->image_lib->initialize($config) should be the same as $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); if I am correct?

Comment: @killstreet good to hear that, suggested adding it to construct to see if it fails to load in there too

Comment: if you dont use it in construct no need to clear() , did you try `$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` ? (changed load with the clear)

Comment: Just done that and it still seems to work, my question remains that if I am not mistaken by the documentation which says : 

`$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';

$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';

$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;

$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

$config['width'] = 75;

$config['height'] = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();`

Should be working just fine, sure it's not a big deal to have $this->image_lib->initialize($config); But just wondering if maybe I made a small and silly mistake?

Comment: @killstreet Yea, seems the user guide has a few mistakes, i don't think they would fix it tho...